# If I have a holomorphic function on the unit disc, do I know anything about the radius of convergence of its series expansion about zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm looking at a proof that assumes only that
$f : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ is holomorphic with $f(0) = 0$

The first step in the proof is to "expand $f$ in a power series centered at $0$ and convergent in all of $\mathbb{D}$."

In other words, $f(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + ...$ inside the disc. Is this a valid step? How do I know that the function's series expansion is valid in the whole disc?

Comment: I believe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Tunococ's link, I found the following: *"the fact that the radius of convergence is always the distance from the center a to the nearest singularity; if there are no singularities (i.e., if ƒ is an entire function), then the radius of convergence is infinite. Strictly speaking, this is not a corollary of the theorem but rather a by-product of the proof."*

Since there are no singularities, then the series is valid for the whole disc!

Comment: This  is incorrect: you may not  assume  that $f$ has no singularity. Counter-example: $f(z)=\frac {1}{3}+\frac {1}{z-3}$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that there are no singularities within the disc.